# Move forwarad and back in Modal bootsrap is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please help, I want a solution to a big problem and my work stopped for many days. I want there to be a possibility to switch between days forward and backward. This thing works well, but the big problem facing me is I want to show these days in Modal, but when there are days in Modal, the movement between The front and back do not work at all

I have the whole code in this link [Jquery, Css Moving between week days with previous next buttons - Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843777/jquery-css-moving-between-week-days-with-previous-next-buttons-carousel/62844319#62844319)

[image]
Modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <div class="day-picker">
                <button type="button" class="day-picker-nav prev">
                    <svg width="12" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(180)">
                        <path class="svg-stroke-container" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#D70F64" d="m3.5,1.5l5,5.5l-5,5.5"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>

                <div class="day-picker-overflow">
                    <ul class="day-picker-week">
                        @foreach($calender_days as $key => $calender_day)

                        <li>
                            <label class="day-picker-day">
                                <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                <span class="day-value button-toggle">{{$calender_day['day_text']}} <span class="day-number">{{(int)$calender_day['day_date']}}</span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="day-picker-nav next">
                    <svg width="12" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(0)">
                        <path class="svg-stroke-container" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#D70F64" d="m3.5,1.5l5,5.5l-5,5.5"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $(".day-picker").each(function() {
    const $week = $(".day-picker-week", this);
    const $days = $(".day-value", this);
    const $prev = $(".prev", this);
    const $next = $(".next", this);

    const visible = Math.floor($week.width() / $days.outerWidth(true));
    const perc = 100 / visible;
    const tot = $days.length;
    const steps = tot - visible;
    let c = 0;
    
    const anim = () => {
      $week.css({transform: `translateX(${-perc*c}%)`});
    }
    
    $prev.on("click", function() {
      c -= 1;
      if (c < 0) c = steps;
      anim();
    });
    
    $next.on("click", function() {
      c += 1;
      if (c > steps) c = 0;
      anim();
    });

  });
```

Comment: is it the same question you are asking again, or it's a variation to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843777/jquery-css-moving-between-week-days-with-previous-next-buttons-carousel/62844319#62844319

Comment: I pointed to this question and I need to solve the issue for modal

Comment: You got to post the modal demo **over here**. Please don't tell us to look in an another question to find your present problem.

Comment: @Viney ok then please go and find an answer for me

Comment: Would it be possible for you to produce a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: it is simply clear, the prev and next buttons dont work when it is in modal but if it was in the page it self it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because `$(".day-picker").width()` was zero before the modal was displayed Which made the amount of `perc` equal to infinity.

Therefore, we have to assign their values to after the modal [shown.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#events)  event.

Improve your script as follows:

```
let visible,
    perc,
    steps,
    c = 0;
const tot = $days.length;

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    visible = Math.floor($week.width() / $days.outerWidth(true));
    perc = 100 / visible;
    steps = tot - visible;
});
```

You can use code snippets:

```js
$(".day-picker").each(function () {
    const $week = $(".day-picker-week", this);
    const $days = $(".day-value", this);
    const $prev = $(".prev", this);
    const $next = $(".next", this);

    let visible,
        perc,
        steps,
        c = 0;
    const tot = $days.length;

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        visible = Math.floor($week.width() / $days.outerWidth(true));
        perc = 100 / visible;
        steps = tot - visible;
    });

    const anim = () => {
        $week.css({ transform: `translateX(${-perc * c}%)` });
    }

    $prev.on("click", function () {
        c -= 1;
        if (c < 0) c = steps;
        anim();
    });

    $next.on("click", function () {
        c += 1;
        if (c > steps) c = 0;
        anim();
    });

});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */

* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

/* DayPicker */

.day-picker {

    --day-width: 70px;
    --day-spacing: 5px;
    --days-visible: 4;

    display: inline-flex;
}

.day-picker-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(var(--day-width) * var(--days-visible) + var(--day-spacing) * var(--days-visible) * 2);
}

.day-picker-week {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}

[name="day-picker"] {
    /* Hide radio buttons */
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.day-value {
    display: block;
    color: #d85c54;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    margin: 0 var(--day-spacing);
    width: var(--day-width);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px currentColor;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

[name="day-picker"]:checked~.day-value {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px currentColor;
}

.day-number {
    display: block;
}

.day-picker-nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</button>

    <div class="day-picker">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <div class="day-picker">
                            <button type="button" class="day-picker-nav prev">
                                <svg width="12" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(180)">
                                    <path class="svg-stroke-container" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#D70F64" d="m3.5,1.5l5,5.5l-5,5.5"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
            
                            <div class="day-picker-overflow">
                                <ul class="day-picker-week">
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">SAT<span class="day-number">11</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">SUN<span class="day-number">12</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">MON<span class="day-number">13</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">TUE<span class="day-number">14</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">WED <span class="day-number">15</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">THU <span class="day-number">16</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="day-picker-day">
                                            <input type="radio" value="" name="day-picker" />
                                            <span class="day-value">FRI <span class="day-number">17</span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
            
                            <button type="button" class="day-picker-nav next">
                                <svg width="12" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(0)">
                                    <path class="svg-stroke-container" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#D70F64" d="m3.5,1.5l5,5.5l-5,5.5"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```